# Access is denied. Check credentials and try again

Tags: node.js, api, ms-office, office365, azure-active-directory

I am trying to access calendar events using the Microsoft Graph API [(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView)](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_calendarview) on node.js following [this permissions guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-integrating-applications/) but I receive the error response :

```
{
   "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "7c2...",
      "date": "2016-07-13T21:19:11"
    }
}
```

The call was made with using :

```
request({url : 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview',  qs : queryParams, 'auth': {'bearer': token}}, function (error, response, body) {
    ...
});
```

The request has a valid token and the call to .../me/ via

```
request({url : 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/', 'auth': {'bearer': token}}, function (error, response, body) {
    ...
});
```

returns :

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
"id":"<valid_id>",
"businessPhones":[],
"displayName":"<valid_name>",
"givenName":"<valid_name>",
"jobTitle":"<valid_title>",
"mail":"<valid_email>",
"mobilePhone":"<valid_cell>",
"officeLocation":null,
"preferredLanguage":"en-US",
"surname":"<valid_name>",
"userPrincipalName":"<valid_email>"}
```

So I am assuming this is an issue with permissions set on https://manage.windowsazure.com/ where I created two applications, one for the node server and one for the web client application.  I am using passport for authentication and the client id and secret for the web client application.

```
var AzureOAuthStrategy = require('passport-azure-oauth').Strategy;
passport.use(new AzureOAuthStrategy({
    clientId:     config.live.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.live.clientSecret,
    tenantId:     config.live.tenant,
    resource:     'https://graph.microsoft.com/', 
    redirectURL:  config.live.callbackURL
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
```

Here is what I set for "permissions to other applications" on the **node application**:

- Windows Azure Active Directory :

  - Delegated Permissions

    - Read all users' full profiles
    - Sign in and read user profile
- Microsoft graph :

  - Delegated Permissions

    - Have full access to user calendars
    - Read user calendars
- (see below)

  - Delegated Permissions

    - Access

Here is what I set for "permissions to other application" on the **web client application**:

- Microsoft Graph :

  - Application Permissions

    - Read and write calendars in all mailboxes
    - Read calendars in all mailboxes
  - Delegated Permissions

    - Sign users in
    - Read user contacts
    - Have full access to user calendars
    - Read user calendars
    - Sign in and read user profile
- Office Exchange 360 Online :

  - Application Permissions

    - Read and write calendars in all mailboxes
    - Read calendars in all mailboxes
  - Delegated Permissions

    - Read user and share calendars
    - Read and write user and shared calendars
    - Read all users' basic profiles
    - Read user profiles
    - Read user contacts
    - Read user calendars
- Windows Azure Active Directory

  - Application Permissions : none
  - Delegated Permissions

    - Sign in and read user profile

I'm not 100% on what the relationship between the permissions set within the azure management portal and specific end point access. I have read the [API scope article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes) but discussion in that article is a bit too conceptual for my needs.

Ultimately I am trying to access and write events to all reservable resources within a tenant id.

Comment: To ensure that the token have enough permission to read the user's calendar. We decode the token from [here](https://jwt.io/). Is there a **Calendars.Read** scope in the token?

Comment: Thanks Fei Xue. I did not know of this site and I will use it for debugging tokens in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by deleting then regenerating the application through https://manage.windowsazure.com/ then updating the client id and secret.  I was, after the fact, able to remove the native client (node) app from the application list and still make the call work.

And while I did not use the reference https://jwt.io/ provided by Fei Xue, I assume it will be invaluable for debugging azure to API permissions in the future.